# Allow Cloud NAT communication with App Engine firewall

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, nat

I have a running cluster on Kubernetes with GCP, and some services running on App Engines, and I'm trying to communicate between them without being able to access the App Engines from the outside.

I created a private Kubernetes cluster with a specific subnetwork, I linked this subnetwork to a Cloud NAT to have a unique egress IP I can whitelist, and I allowed this IP in the App Engine firewall rules.

However, when I request my app engines from the cluster, I get a 403 response because it doesn't pass through the firewall. But if I connect to my Kubernetes pod and try to request a site to know my IP, I get the IP I set in the Cloud NAT.

I found in the Cloud NAT documentation that the translation to internal IPs is realised before the application of the firewall rules (https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#firewall_rules).

Is there a way to retrieve this internal IP? Or another way to secure the services?

Comment: Update: I tried to allow 0.0.0.0 in the firewall rules, and it works approximately 3 out of 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#private_google_access) never applies to traffic sent to the public IP addresses for Google APIs and services. Requests sent to Google APIs and services never use the external IPs configured for Cloud NAT as their sources.

I suggest you to deploy a [Internal load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing). Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing makes your cluster's services accessible to applications outside of your cluster that use the same VPC network and are located in the same GCP region.